# SSH is unable to resolve local domain names

Tags: ssh, hostname, avahi, mdns

I'm trying to connect to several computers via their hostnames since they get their IP via DHCP. I can successfully ping the machines via `ping host-01.local`.

`ping`, `wget`, `avahi-resolve` and even Firefox all send out the required mDNS packages, which I checked throug Wireshark (UDP on port 5353).

However `ssh` doesn't seem to try to resolve the adresses at all. There are no mDNS queries issued and the output for `ssh host-01.local` just says:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname host-01.local: Device or resource busy
```

For `ssh -vvv host-01.local` it is:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "host-01.local" port 22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname host-01.local: Device or resource busy
```

The client is running Linux Mint. The network I'm in doesn't seem to matter. Everything else related to `avahi` seems to work just fine.

Comment: Can you run `ssh -vvv host-01.local`  to see what's happening?

Comment: @ValentinBajrami I don't know if there's anything useful but I updated the question with your suggestion.

Comment: Do you have something in your `~/.ssh/config`   file. Also does the `ping` command return you the correct address of the server you are trying to ssh to?

Comment: @ValentinBajrami I do not have a config file at that location. The `ping` command returns the correct address, as does the `avahi-resolve` command.

Comment: maybe you can check this link: https://superuser.com/questions/704785/avahi-ping-cant-resolve-hostname-but-nslookup-can

Comment: @ValentinBajrami So far I couldn't figure it out. However your link reminded me that I once mucked about with a DNS server and might have changed some settings, but I can't remember exactly what I did.
Also I found another clue with systemd-resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I had the 32-bit version of `ssh` on my system. Installing the 64-bit version seems to have solved all of my problems.

After looking through the `strace` of the command I noticed `ssh` had failed trying to load a bunch of libraries. This baffled me at first because most of these libraries are installed on my system, until I noticed some of the paths wich included `i386-linux-gnu`. That's when I realized I must have the wrong package installed.